# How to set default apps for mail and web browser to Outlook & IE on W10 using Registry?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-registry

Trying to set default apps for mail & browser. Tried changing it manually on **Default apps**, which changes the value of **ProgID** in the below registry path:

```
$RegistryPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\mailto\UserChoice"
```

Then, when I use below snippet, it reflects in the registry, but it resets to **MAIL** in **Default apps**, and also throws a notification stating it was reset.

```
If (!(Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "ProgId" -Type String -Value "Outlook.URL.mailto.15" -Force | Out-Null
}
```

Similarly tried for IE, but it resets to MS Edge with a similar notification. Trying to do this via, registry as it needs to be done on a large scale.

Answer (score 0):

First to set MS Outlook as your default mail client, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Appkey\15` key and create a new string value named `ShellExecute` and set it's data to `"Full path of OUTLOOK.exe"`.

And to set IE as your default web browser, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Appkey\7` and create a string value named `ShellExecute` and set data to "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome`.

Hope that helps

Comment: I think these are for settings the keyboard shortcuts, I tried them, and they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found some information which might be useful to you. For your reference:

Set default browser via GPO
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/set-default-browser

Registry keys to set Outlook as default email program. Notice: different versions of Outlook client may need different values. https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/how-can-i-configure-outlook-be-default-mail-client